# No such file or directory when loading image using node-canvas

Tags: javascript, node-canvas

Above is the code I'm attempting to run, for some reason the 'no such file or directory' error is thrown but i know for a fact the image is there. I can't see anything wrong with the current code.

```js
async generateWishBackground(ctx) {
  const wishBackground = loadImage('./image.jpg');

  ctx.drawImage(wishBackground, 0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);
}
```

Comment: I'm assuming `loadImage()` is a function you created. Could you show us the code for it?

Comment: **./image.jpg** is a relative path. I think the base directory of this relative path is not the directory in which your picture is.

Comment: ```loadImage()``` is destructed from node-canvas. Although the function itself works fine with links. I've seen examples online on how to use ```loadImage()``` with local images and their use method isn't any different from mine.

Furthermore BETOMBO, I'm using an actual image path, but I just replaced it with image.jpg as an example.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.